# Evernote like Action Bar drop down menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to figure out how to create a User Information dropdown menu exactly like what evernote uses in the screen shot below.

Dropdowns and normal spinners don't seem to support a Header value where the Username is.

Does anyone have any ideas how to to implement something like this with a header, custom fields in the dropdown list and spinner icon in bottom right of header.

Also, the sample at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown is not what I need unless it can be expanded for header and custom entries.

Supporting Android 3.1+

Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AhC8.jpg)